# Binary tree insert node procedure is not working as desired (Scheme)

Tags: scheme, lisp, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I implemented a function for inserting nodes in a binary tree.
 
Tree node is a list of the form `(left-node key right-node)`.
`(insert tree n)` is my insert node function, where tree is a list of tree nodes in a binary search tree and I want to add the key value n as a new node.

So, `(insert '(((() 4 ()) 5 (() 2 ())) 6 ()) 7)` gives the output as 
`(((() 4 ()) 5 (() 2 ())) 6 (() 7 ()))`.

Now, what I want to do is something like this : 
**1**. Define a list of values.
`` (define (f) (list '1 `2 `3 `4 `5 )) ``
**2**. Loop through the list and enter the values one by one in a tree, starting from an empty tree.

So, when I tried to do step 2, I did the following :

```
(define x ()) ;; Tree x is initially empty
(insert x 2)  ;; This prints (() 2 ())
(insert x 1)  ;; This prints (() 1 ()). I want it to be ((() 1 ()) 2 ()).
(insert x 3)  ;; This prints (() 3 ()). I want it to be ((() 1 ()) 2 (() 3 ())).
```

That is where I am stuck.
I provide my insert function below.

```
(define (left tree) (list-ref tree 0))
(define (value tree) (list-ref tree 1))
(define (right tree) (list-ref tree 2))

(define (insert tree n)
  (cond
    [( null? tree ) ( list () n () )]
    [(< n (cadr tree)) (list (insert (car tree) n) (cadr tree) (caddr tree))] 
    [(> n (cadr tree)) (list (car tree) (cadr tree) (insert (caddr tree) n))] 
    [else tree] 
  )
)
```

Can someone suggest how I can achieve my intended outputs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has three problems.  Note that in the following I'm kind of rude about the code: I'm just being blunt as I'm writing quickly, and I'm *not* trying to be rude to you personally!

### You have not defined all the abstractions you need

You want at least a function which constructs tree nodes, a function which tests for a null tree and an object which represents null trees.  Here is a more complete set of abstractions:

```
(define null-tree '())

(define (tree-null? tree)
  (eq? tree null-tree))

(define (make-tree-node left key right)
  (list left key right))

(define (left tree)
  (list-ref tree 0))

(define (value tree)
  (list-ref tree 1))

(define (right tree)
  (list-ref tree 2))
```

### Your `insert` function does not use abstractions

It does not use the ones you have defined, let alone the missing ones, causing it to be an incomprehensible 1960s-style mess.  Here is a version of it which uses abstractions throughout (this also fixes some weird spacing and dangling paren problems which are helping no-one reading your code):

```
(define (insert tree n)
  (cond
    [(tree-null? tree)
     (make-tree-node null-tree n null-tree)]
    [(< n (value tree))
     (make-tree-node (insert (left tree) n)
                     (value tree)
                     (right tree))]
    [(> n (value tree))
     (make-tree-node (left tree)
                     (value tree)
                     (insert (right tree) n))]
    [else tree]))
```

### You haven't understood that `insert` *is a function*

It takes a tree and *returns a tree which has the element added to it*, rather than taking a tree and adding the element to it by side-effect.  `insert` never modifies any of its arguments but rather constructs a suitable new tree (or returns the existing tree if the element being added is already there).

So in order to add a sequence of elements, for instance, you need to construct a sequence of trees with `insert` which have those elements added:

```
(define (insert-elements tree elts)
  (if (null? elts)
      tree
      (insert-elements (insert tree (first elts)) (rest elts))))
```

Now:

```
> (insert-elements null-tree '(7 1 2 3 4 7 202 48 20 0))
'(((() 0 ()) 1 (() 2 (() 3 (() 4 ())))) 7 (((() 20 ()) 48 ()) 202 ()))
```

---

### Why use abstractions

If I change the abstractions for trees:

```
(define null-tree '/)

(define (tree-null? tree)
  (eq? tree null-tree))

(define (make-tree-node left key right)
  (vector left key right))

(define (left tree)
  (vector-ref tree 0))

(define (value tree)
  (vector-ref tree 1))

(define (right tree)
  (vector-ref tree 2))
```

Then I can use *exactly the same function* with this new tree type:

```
> (insert-elements null-tree '(7 1 2 3 4 7 202 48 20 0))
'#(#(#(/ 0 /) 1 #(/ 2 #(/ 3 #(/ 4 /)))) 7 #(#(#(/ 20 /) 48 /) 202 /))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, for clarifying everything in such a detailed explanation. Now, that I think of it, I had really misunderstood that the insert function returns a new tree. Also, thank you for pointing out the additional abstractions that make life a lot easier :) .

Comment: Regarding the weird indentation I had used, I am very new to Scheme, so I was indenting my code like that partly to gain some resemblance with other languages and also to help me figure out what is going on in the code.

Comment: @Anjishnu: I think it's tempting to do the closing-paren-on-a-line thing because it makes it look like C-ish languages, but it's really a mistake, because all those dangling parens are just noise: the parens should *almost vanish* when reading well-written Lisp code (think of it as like reading Python code!)

Comment: Yes, I am more used to C++ than Python. But thanks for pointing it out. I will ensure that Lisp code I write in the future is less C-ish :)